# Convert numerical expressions from Axis Y to Axis X

Tags: excel

I want to convert a row of numbers that represent the Y axis on a standard curve

I know the answer of the X Axis, but I wonder how to obtain those numbers using an Excel Formula;

This row represents the X axis (target result) that I want to get;

```
-0,4949
-0,3979
-0,3010
-0,2041
-0,1079
```

This row represent the Y axis (Starting point);

```
18,19
18,70
19,31
19,88
20,38
```

Comment: How do you do it by hand?  Not sure there is a way to back into the x values.  This may be a better question for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: that's the great question; this is for a girl who works with Biology Science, she use a calculator to get that Bob Marley stuff, I want to help her to make it on Excel, but I dunno how she does it, for real and her explanaitions confused me more that clear my mind....

Comment: Then again you are asking in the wrong place, As far as I know unless you know the relationship(formula) between X and Y one set of numbers will not get you the other.

Comment: Now if you know the formula yes we can help you get the x's.

Comment: Even if you don't know the formula, Excel can help, if the formula isn't too complex. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an **Excel Trendline** to get a formula suggestion:

- Put your values into two columns in Excel and give them a headline
- Select all data and add a diagram of type "XY dot"
- Select the graph line and "add a trendline" via right mouseclick
- within trendline options:

  - decide which formula type results in a good trendline, e. g. "linear"
  - "show formula in diagram"

Result as line and formula (your values are blue, and the trendline is dotted)

[image: Screenshot of XY diagram]

You can exchange X and Y, change color of the trendline and show more decimals if necessary by selecting the formula and adapting the number format code:

[image: Screenshot with more decimals]

And there are also formulas to calculate it directly from your value columns:

- Linear regressions (like in this case) can be calculated with [FORECAST.LINEAR](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/forecast-linear-function-38e2a419-7415-4037-8761-93f3992ace87) function (in Portuguese Excel: PREVISÃO.LINEAR) to calculate a missing value.
- Exponential growth can be calculated with [GROWTH](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/growth-function-541a91dc-3d5e-437d-b156-21324e68b80d).

Comment: That's near from what I get, but I wonder where she get the X values